# How to bind a dependencyproperty of a usercontrol to a property of usercontrol's viemodel?

Tags: wpf, data-binding, binding, mvvm, mvvm-light

I have a textbox and a button in a usercontrol ,and it opens a window in button clickto select something and put in the textbox:
like this:

```
  string myProperty;
    public string MyProperty
    {
        get
        {
            return myProperty;
        }
        set
        {
            myProperty= value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("MyProperty");
        }
    }

 public ICommand buttonClickCommand
 {
    get { return new RelayCommand(ShowItemView); }
 }
 void ShowItemView()
  {  
  var ItemViewModel = new ItemViewModel();
  var ItemView = new ItemView();
  ItemView .DataContext = ItemViewModel ;
  ItemView .ShowDialog();
  if (ItemViewModel .SelectedItem != null)
       myProperty= ItemViewModel .SelectedItem.Name;
  }
```

and now i want to create two instances of the usercontrol in a window ,and bind their text box to two properties of the viewmodel of window,so i make a dependency property for that like this:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty OperandTextValueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("OperandTextValue",
           typeof(string),
           typeof(DefaultSpecItemControl),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata()
            {
                PropertyChangedCallback = OnOperandTextValue,
                BindsTwoWayByDefault = true
            });

    public string OperandTextValue
    {
        get
        {
            return (string)GetValue(OperandTextValueProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(OperandTextValueProperty, value);

        }
    }
```

and bind it to the properties in viewmodel of window,but i don't know how can i bind it to the viemodel of the usercontrol,in this case to bind it to MyProperty in viewmodel of the control.So

1:Is there any way to bind a dependencyProperty of a usercontrol to it's own viewmodel?

2:Am I on the right road?

thanks in advance.

Comment: if `ItemView` is a dialog with ability to cancel/close, use next lines:

    if (ItemView .ShowDialog() == true)
        if (ItemViewModel .SelectedItem != null)
            myProperty= ItemViewModel .SelectedItem.Name;

or similar to this.

Comment: Why do you think you have to define a DependenyProperty in your Window, if you are following MVVM pattern then you'd better to define only simple properties in Windows's ViewModel. Then Tthese properties should return the value from the related UserControl's ViewModel. Your question is not clear to me, please explain more and better.

Comment: @Sam:I don't define the dependencyProperty in Window,i define it in usercontrol.and i want to bind it to the userControl's viewmodel.

Comment: @stukselbax:I don't understand what you mean!I think my question is not clear!it's because of my bad english!:D i have a dependency property named OperandTextValue in my usercontrol and a property named Myproperty in usercontrol's viewmodel,and now i want to bind them together!!because i have to set that's value in usercontrol's viewmodel.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a way to bind a dependency property of a user control to its own view model, although, in most cases you will want to bind the UI of the user control to itself, i.e.

```
LayoutRoot.DataContext = this;
```

For general guidance on user control design and binding, see [this tutorial I wrote](http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2012/02/a-simple-pattern-for-creating-re-useable-usercontrols-in-wpf-silverlight/).

Comment: :thanks,but i didn't understand,would you please explain more?what's LayoutRoot?!!

Comment: @Raha - check out the tutorial I linked to. LayoutRoot is the root element of your user control.

Comment: @ColinE, UserControl by itself does not have a property named LayoutRoot, I think 'LayoutRoot' is the name that default template for UserControl uses.